# access array elements by value

Tags: php

I have an array like :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [223] => Array
        (

            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => TTTT
                    [tribeid] => 31
                    [numusers] => 10
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-05-28 18:30:34
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => KKKKK
                    [tribeid] => 32
                    [numusers] => 11
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-05-28 18:32:12
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => RRRR
                    [tribeid] => 33
                    [numusers] => 5
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-05-28 18:53:17
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => mytehhhhhst2
                    [tribeid] => 34
                    [numusers] => 4
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-05-28 18:56:15
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => yog
                    [tribeid] => 58
                    [numusers] => 1
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-06-01 12:32:47
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => newFunc
                    [tribeid] => 63
                    [numusers] => 1
                    [dateCreated] => 2012-06-01 12:45:01
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tribeName] => Jghj
                    [numusers] => 0
                    [tribeid] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Here, 223 is the key value, each time will be new. I access it as key($array). I will get 223 value.
But how can I access its value e.g tribeName? plz help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  foreach ($array as $value) {
           foreach($value as $data )
               echo $data->tribeName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will have to iterate through the array and check each element manually.
You can also write a function for this, of course.

If you would need to compare for the entire array element, not just a member of it, you could use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to determine the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
foreach($var as $key => $val)
    {
            $kkv = $var[$key];
            $inarray = $kkv[0];
            print_r($inarray);
            echo $inarray['tribeName'];
    }
```